# $x++ result always gives 1

Tags: php, increment

```
<?
include('config.php');
$z=$_GET['qnum'];
$j=$_GET['num'];
$n=$_GET['num'];

$sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM qustion where qnum='$z'");
while($l=mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{
    $m++;
}
$sql=mysql_query("DELETE FROM qustion WHERE qnum='$z' and num='$n'");
if($n!=$m)
{
    $sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM qustion where qnum= '$z' order by num");
    while($r=mysql_fetch_array($sql))
    {
        $x++;
        if($x<=9)
        {
            $x="0$x";
        }
        $sql= "UPDATE qustion SET num='$x' WHERE qnum='$z'";                
        if( !mysql_query($sql,$link) )
        die( 'Error: ' . mysql_error() );   
    }
}
?>
```

my database updates but all my num column is updated to 01.i want it to be a sequence 01,02....depends on the number of rows on my database.

Comment: I don't think you meant to put this in `x++` tag :)

Comment: `while($l=mysql_fetch_array($sql)) { $m++; }` what is this? why don't you use something like `mysql_numrows` ?

Comment: sorry for all those codes and the tag.I'm newbie in php :)

Answer (score 2):

Rather than zero-padding in your PHP, why not define your database column appropriately?

```
ALTER TABLE `qustion` MODIFY `num` TINYINT(2) UNSIGNED ZEROFILL
```

Or, better still, format on the way out instead of on the way in:

```
$q = /* some code to get the question data */
echo sprintf("%02s",$q['num']);
```

Comment: i alter the talbe but still same result

Comment: If you went with the `ALTER TABLE` option, then you should just insert `$x` without changing it - remove the whole `if( $x <= 9)` bit.

Comment: yes i've also tried that but same result.my code is just $x++ then update.i still can't figure out the problem and why it's always 1.

Comment: Wait a second... what's your table structure? If you `echo $x." ";` in your loop, what do you get?

Comment: num is an integer.i tried to print it but the result is 1.the output should be 123 because i have 3 data on the table.

Comment: Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\....

Comment: i think that is the problem.it terminates the process before it's completed.I don't know much about php.

Comment: it's not unique in the table but you can't enter the same number.how can i fix this?